# Can't select row in R - can't figure out why

Tags: r

I am trying to remove two rows from my dataset with this simple line of code:

`my_data_screen <- my_data [-influential]`

However, I get the error message `Error: Can't negate columns that don't exist.`

(The "influential" variable simply contains two numbers of rows, which is the result of [calculating outliers from my sample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164099/removing-outliers-based-on-cooks-distance-in-r-language).)

Even why I try do something as simple as targeting a specific row (i.e. `my_data [37]`), I get the same error message.

Why is R interpreting my command as targeting **columns**, rather than **rows**?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `my_data` as `data.frame`, then you should use

```
my_data[37, ]
```

since `my_data[37]` is indexing `my_data` in terms of columns by default.

Please read about https://rspatial.org/intr/4-indexing.html

Comment: @KaizerLBA You need to tell `R` you want to index by rows, then `,` is the the thing.

Answer (score 1):

Hi with your code R cannot understand if you select a row or a column.

As @ThomasIsCoding suggest you should use:

```
my_data_screen <- my_data[-influential,]
```

Comma indicate there are rows, if you want to delete columns the following specification is the right one:

```
my_data_screen <- my_data[,-influential]
```

In summary, the position of commas tell R if you want to delete columns or rows.

Comment: I've wondering about this, thank you! I finally understood the significance of the comma now.

Comment: @KaizerLBA You can also select rows or columns with their index in a df.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with tidyverse, you should use :

- The filter() function to remove rows : `filter(!(influential %in% specified_values))`
- The select() function to remove columns : `select(-influential)`